# Algorithm faster than Newton's for calculating $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: computational-mathematics, fixed-point-iteration

It is well known that the iteration scheme

$$ x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2} (x_n + \frac{2}{x_n })$$

converges to $\sqrt{2}$ very fast. More precisely, it converges quadratically. The problem is, is there any even faster algorithm? Namely, can we find another polynomial $P(x, 1/x)$ of $x$ and $1/x$ with **rational coefficients**, such that the iteration scheme

$$x_{n+1} = P \left(x_n , \frac{1}{x_n} \right)$$

converges even faster?

The conjecture is that no such algorithm exists. But I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: Couldn't you iterate this, i.e. find $x_{n+2}$ from $x_n$?

Comment: Good idea! But it seems that the conjectures needs a minor modification only.

Comment: Will you be happy if the polynomial $P(x,1/x)$ is replaced with a rational function $Q(x)$ with rational number coefficients?

Comment: I think the computational cost of computing the polynomial at each step should also be considered, as well as the loss of precision in some cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one that converges faster (fewer steps), at least in a certain range:

$x_{n+1}=-{1\over32}x_n^3+{5\over8}x_n+{7\over8}{1\over x_n}$

That has the desired properties of $P(\sqrt 2)=\sqrt 2$ and a local minimum at $x=\sqrt 2$:

[image]

It can be seen that the curve (and thus the iterates starting from $x < 3$ anyway) is closer to $\sqrt 2$ than the Newton curve.

The ratio of first seven iterates to $\sqrt 2$, starting from $x=3$:

```
new&improved      Newton
2.121320343559642 2.121320343559642
0.935443345944703 1.296362432175337
1.001184535464119 1.033875824007604
1.000000349950901 1.000554985146933
1.000000000000031 1.000000153918834
1.000000000000000 1.000000000000012
1.000000000000000 1.000000000000000
```

Of course, it's only about one step ahead, and there's the additional cost of the cube factor